# Difference between Asmuth-Bloom and Shamir's Secret Sharing

Tags: secret-sharing, threshold-cryptography

Both Asmuth and Shamir are threshold based secret sharing schemes and perfectly secure.

In which point of view  Asmuth bloom secret sharing scheme is better than Shamir secret sharing scheme.

Could you please give me anyone reason Asmuth bloom secret sharing scheme is better than Shamir secret sharing scheme.

Comment: Actually, Asmuth is not perfectly secure, as it leaks probabilistic information about the shared secret; that is, even though with insufficient shares, no possible shared secret value can be ruled out, however some secrets are more probable than others.

Answer (score 3):

As has been commented, Asmuth-Bloom is does not always give a perfect scheme.  The [original paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1056651) gives a condition on the primes to maximise "sharpness", which is what they call their measure of closeness to perfection.

A [recent paper at Asiacrypt 2018](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/837.pdf) gives fairly detailed analysis of the differences, and they also construct a new scheme using similar techniques.  In the introduction they remark:

> In  a  word,  Shamir’s  scheme  is  ideal  and  easy  to  construct 
>   while  Asmuth- Bloom’s  scheme  is  not  ideal,  hard  to  construct 
>   but  more  natural  and  neat  in constructing  weighted  SS  scheme.

So while Shamir's scheme is very good for threshold schemes by most metrics, if one wants to construct secret sharing schemes for *weighted* threshold access structures then Asmuth-Bloom, these authors claim, has a more "natural" generalisation.  (Weighted threshold schemes are [defined in the same paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/837.pdf?page=18), and are basically a way of fine-tuning the qualified sets of the access structure.)